# How to do lazy dataTable in Primefaces with Spring and Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I have to turn my dataTable to lazy dataTable. How can I do it? Here is my sample code:

**IndexBean.java**

```
@Name("indexBean")
public class IndexBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    UserService userService;
    private List<User> userList;

    @Inject
    MessageService messageService;
    private List<Message> messageList;

    private Integer dataTableRendered;

    public void getAllUser() {
        setDataTableRendered(1);
        userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        userList = userService.getAllUser();
        if (userList.size() > 0) {
            addMessageSuccess("Success", "Success");
        } else {
            addMessageError("Failure", "Failure!");
        }
    }

    public void getAllMessages() {
        setDataTableRendered(2);
        messageList = new ArrayList<Message>();
        messageList = messageService.getAllMessages();
        if (messageList.size() > 0) {
            addMessageSuccess("Success", "Success");
        } else {
            addMessageError("Failure", "Failure!");
        }
    }

    public void addMessageSuccess(String summary, String detail) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, summary, detail);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }

    public void addMessageError(String summary, String detail) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, summary, detail);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }

    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }
    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }
    public List<Message> getMessageList() {
        return messageList;
    }
    public void setMessageList(List<Message> messageList) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
    }
    public Integer getDataTableRendered() {
        return dataTableRendered;
    }
    public void setDataTableRendered(Integer dataTableRendered) {
        this.dataTableRendered = dataTableRendered;
    }
}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head></h:head>
<p:layout fullPage="true">

    <!-- Status Waiting Dialog -->
    <p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()"
        onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()" />

    <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false"
        closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="true"
        header="Please wait...">
        <p:graphicImage value="/images/loader.gif"
            style=" float: left;position: relative;left: 30%;" />
    </p:dialog>

    <!-- Left Layout -->
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" id="west">

        <p:growl autoUpdate="true" id="infoMessage" showDetail="true"
            showSummary="true" sticky="false" />

        <p:commandButton value="Get Users"
            actionListener="#{indexBean.getAllUser}"
            update="infoMessage,centerForm,centerForm:userTable" />

        <p:commandButton value="Get Messages"
            actionListener="#{indexBean.getAllMessages}"
            update="infoMessage,centerForm,centerForm:messageRaporTable" />

    </p:layoutUnit>

    <!-- Center Layout -->
    <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="center">

        <h:form id="centerForm">

            <!-- User dataTable -->
            <p:dataTable id="userTable" var="user"
                value="#{indexBean.userList }" paginator="true" rows="10"
                lazy="true" rendered="#{indexBean.dataTableRendered ==1}"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,25,50,100">

                <p:column headerText="userid" sortBy="#{user.userId}"
                    filterBy="#{user.userId}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.userId}"></h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="username" sortBy="#{user.userName}"
                    filterBy="#{user.userName}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.userName}"></h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="firstname" sortBy="#{user.userFirstName}"
                    filterBy="#{user.userFirstName}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.userFirstName}"></h:outputText>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:column headerText="Message Id" 
                    filterBy="#{message.messageId}"
                    sortBy="#{message.messageId}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{message.messageId}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Sender" 
                    sortBy="#{message.messageSender}" filterBy="#{message.messageSender}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{message.messageSender}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Receiver" 
                    sortBy="#{message.messageReceiver}"
                    filterBy="#{message.messageReceiver}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{message.messageReceiver}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Subject"
                    sortBy="#{message.messageSubject}"
                    filterBy="#{message.messageSubject}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{message.messageSubject}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Message"
                    sortBy="#{message.messageText}"
                    filterBy="#{message.messageText}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{message.messageText}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

        </h:form>

    </p:layoutUnit>

</p:layout>
```

**UserService.java**

```
public interface UserService {

    public List<User> getAllUser();
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service("userService")
@Component
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {


    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        return userDAO.getAllUser();
    }

}
```

**UserDAO.java**

```
public interface UserDAO {

    public List<User> getAllUser();

}
```

**UserDAOImpl.java**  - Actually this **sql** more complicated.

```
@Component
@Repository("userDAO")
public class UserDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements UserDAO {


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        String sql = "select * from SECRETDB.USER";


        try {
            Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql).addScalar("userOID", StringType.INSTANCE)
                    .addScalar("userName", StringType.INSTANCE).addScalar("firstName", StringType.INSTANCE)
                    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class)).setCacheable(false)
                    .setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);

            userList = query.list();
            getSession().clear();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            getSession().clear();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return userList;
    }
```

**User.java**

```
public class User {

    private String userOID;
    private String userName;
    private String firstName;

    public String getUserOID() {
        return userOID;
    }

    public void setUserOID(String userOID) {
        this.userOID = userOID;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

}
```

**HibernateDaoSupport.java**

```
public abstract class HibernateDaoSupport {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual coding problem? I see all non lazy java code and only a lazy attribute on the datatable. Like posted below, start by using the showcase, searching the internet, bang your head, bang your head again and then get back with real coding problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I am doing it.

```
public class ImagePaginator extends LazyDataModel<PhotoObject> {

private ISession session;
private int startId;
private int endId;
private User user;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private SearchController searchController;

public ImagePaginator(User user, SearchController searchController) {
    this.session = user.getSession();
    this.user = user;
    this.searchController = searchController;
}

@Override
public List<PhotoObject> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
        Map<String, Object> filters) {

    // collect paginated data from server
    Collection<IObject> photos = searchController.getResultAccount().getPaginatedObjects(first, first + 3,
            SystemConstants.PHOTO);
    List<PhotoObject> data = new ArrayList<PhotoObject>();

    for (IObject resultPhoto : photos) {
        IPhoto photo = (IPhoto) resultPhoto;
        data.add(new PhotoObject(photo));
    }

    this.setRowCount(data.size() + 1);

    return data;
}

@Override
public Object getRowKey(PhotoObject photoObject) {
    return photoObject.getId();
}

public ISession getSession() {
    return session;
}

public void setSession(ISession session) {
    this.session = session;
}

public int getStartId() {
    return startId;
}

public void setStartId(int startId) {
    this.startId = startId;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public SearchController getSearchController() {
    return searchController;
}

public void setSearchController(SearchController searchController) {
    this.searchController = searchController;
}

public int getEndId() {
    return endId;
}

public void setEndId(int endId) {
    this.endId = endId;
}
```

just like you I use a service to retrieve the results. The sql that I am sending (Depending in the situation) is:

```
public List<IEntity> retrievePaginatedById(String classType, String targetId, String status, int id, int offset,
        int limit, boolean forContactRequestNotification) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String hql = null;
    if (forContactRequestNotification) {
        hql = "FROM " + classType + " D WHERE " + targetId + "=" + "'" + id + "' AND D.status = '" + status
                + "' ORDER BY D.id DESC";
    } else {
        hql = "FROM " + classType + " D WHERE " + targetId + "=" + "'" + id + "'" + " ORDER BY D.id DESC";
    }
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql).setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(limit);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<IEntity> results = query.list();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your datatable in index.xhtml i see

```
  value="#{indexBean.userList }" paginator="true" rows="10"
            lazy="true"
```

where userList is pointing to

```
  private List<User> userList;
```

This is wrong. It should be

```
  private LazyUserDataModel<User> userList
```

Please read [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml) and [userguide](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf) pages 167-168 to implement LazyDataModel. Nobody here is going to ***teach*** you to implement it. An example of a generic lazydatamodel using hibernate and JPA is below.

```
  public class GenericLazyDataModel<T> extends LazyDataModel<T> {

@Transient
protected static Logger debugLogger = Logger.getLogger("DebugLogger");

protected EntityManager entityManager;
protected String hqlQuery;
private String countQuery;
protected List<SortFieldInfoDTO> defaultSortFields;
protected List<T> currentObjectList;
protected List<Object> parameterValues;
protected List<String> parameterName;

protected List<Object> filterFieldValues;
protected List<String> filterFieldName;


public GenericLazyDataModel(EntityManager entityManager, String hqlQuery,
        String countQuery, List<SortFieldInfoDTO> sortFieldInfos,
        List<Object> parameterValues, List<String> parameterName) {
    super();
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
    this.hqlQuery = hqlQuery;
    this.countQuery = countQuery;
    this.defaultSortFields = sortFieldInfos;
    this.parameterValues = parameterValues;
    this.parameterName = parameterName;
    this.setRowCount(calculateRecordCount());

}

@Override
public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
        SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

    String sqlQuery = hqlQuery;
    int filterCount = 0;
    if(sortOrder==null){
        sortOrder=SortOrder.ASCENDING;
    }

    if (filterFieldValues != null && filterFieldName != null) {
        filterFieldValues.clear();
        filterFieldName.clear();
    }
    for (Iterator<String> iterator = filters.keySet().iterator(); iterator
            .hasNext();) {
        String filterField = iterator.next();
        if (debugLogger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            debugLogger.info("Filter Field Name " + filterField);
        }

        // Check if the HQL Query already has a where clause
        if (sqlQuery.toLowerCase().indexOf("where") != -1) {
            sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " and  " + filterField
                    + " like :filterFieldValue" + filterCount;
        } else {
            sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " where  " + filterField
                    + " like :filterFieldValue" + filterCount;
        }

        if (filterFieldValues == null) {
            filterFieldValues = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }

        if (filterFieldName == null) {
            filterFieldName = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        filterFieldValues.add(((String)filters.get(filterField)).toUpperCase() + "%");
        filterFieldName.add("filterFieldValue" + filterCount);
        filterCount++;

    }


    //************************
    boolean isOrderFieldFound=Boolean.FALSE;
    if(sortField !=null && !sortField.isEmpty()){
        isOrderFieldFound=Boolean.TRUE;
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " order by  " + sortField+(sortOrder==SortOrder.ASCENDING?" ASC ":" DESC ");
    }
    if(isOrderFieldFound){

        if(defaultSortFields !=null && !defaultSortFields.isEmpty()){
            for(SortFieldInfoDTO fld:defaultSortFields){
                if(!sqlQuery.contains(fld.getAliasedFieldName()))   sqlQuery=sqlQuery+" , "+fld.getAliasedFieldName()+(fld.getSortOrder()==SortOrder.ASCENDING?" ASC ":" DESC ");
            }
        }

    }else{
        if(defaultSortFields !=null && !defaultSortFields.isEmpty()){
            int index=0;
            for(SortFieldInfoDTO fld:defaultSortFields){
                if(index==0){
                    if(!sqlQuery.contains(fld.getAliasedFieldName())) sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " order by  " + fld.getAliasedFieldName()+(fld.getSortOrder()==SortOrder.ASCENDING?" ASC ":" DESC ");
                    index++;
                }else{
                    if(!sqlQuery.contains(fld.getAliasedFieldName())) sqlQuery=sqlQuery+" , "+fld.getAliasedFieldName()+(fld.getSortOrder()==SortOrder.ASCENDING?" ASC ":" DESC ");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //*********************************
    if (debugLogger.isInfoEnabled())debugLogger.info("sqlQuery:"+sqlQuery);
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sqlQuery);
    int parameterCount = 0;
    if (parameterValues != null) {
        for (Iterator<Object> iterator = parameterValues.iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) {
            Object type = iterator.next();
            query.setParameter(parameterName.get(parameterCount), type);
            parameterCount++;
        }
    }

    int parameterCount1 = 0;
    if (filterFieldValues != null && !filterFieldValues.equals("")) {
        for (Iterator<Object> iterator = filterFieldValues.iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) {
            Object type = iterator.next();
            query.setParameter(filterFieldName.get(parameterCount1), type);
            parameterCount1++;
        }
    }

    if (debugLogger.isInfoEnabled())debugLogger.info("first page value " + first);
    if (debugLogger.isInfoEnabled())debugLogger.info("pageSize page value " + pageSize);

    query.setFirstResult(first);
    query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    currentObjectList = query.getResultList();
    return currentObjectList;
}

private int calculateRecordCount() {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery);
    int parameterCount = 0;       
    if (parameterValues != null) {
        for (Iterator<Object> iterator = parameterValues.iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) {
            Object type = iterator.next();
            query.setParameter(parameterName.get(parameterCount), type);
            parameterCount++;
        }
    }

    if (filterFieldValues != null) {
        for (Iterator<Object> iterator = filterFieldValues.iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) {
            Object type = iterator.next();
            query.setParameter(filterFieldName.get(parameterCount), type);
            parameterCount++;
        }
    }

    Long rowCount = (Long) query.getSingleResult();
    if (debugLogger.isInfoEnabled()) {
        debugLogger.info("rowCount Application Data Model" + rowCount);
    }
    return rowCount.intValue();

}

public List<T> getCurrentObjectList() {
    return currentObjectList;
}
```

}

Using this and learning on your own figure this out and good luck.

Comment: Extensive answer… You could create a specific question about using a generic LazyDataModel in stackoverflow and post this as an answer. The question above is not the right place for this answer

Comment: The JPA `CriteriaBuilder` API is meant for creating dynamic queries.